# Microdata error: "The property http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name is not recognized by Google"

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

The way I understand it, the Schema.org type called `Product` inherits from the type `Thing`. So why does this:

```
<meta  itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="https://some.url" itemref="md25" />
<div class="field-item even" itemprop="description http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/description">
    long description goes here
</div>
<meta  itemprop="name http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name" content="Blueair Pro L" id="md25" />
```

… fail, when I enter it [in Google's testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)?

I get error:

> The property `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name` is not recognized by Google for an object of type Product.

But `description` is part of `Thing` and `Product` inherits from it. It even [shows it on the Schema.org page here](http://schema.org/Product).

So why is this error being thrown?

Comment: May I ask if you have written this markup yourself? If not, I’d be interested to see where this is coming from (as it’s rare to see the FOAF vocabulary being used in Microdata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted message is about the property `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name`, not about the property `http://schema.org/name` or `http://schema.org/description`.

And it doesn’t say that it would be an error (in Microdata, it is valid to use [absolute URLs as properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute)), it just says that Google doesn’t recognize it. Which is not surprising, because Google [doesn’t](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies#technical_guidelines) document support for the FOAF vocabulary.

On a side note: You can’t use the `meta` with `itemscope` like that. You should use a `div` (or a more specific) element instead.